# Replace /var moved to other partition

Tags: debian

Some months ago, i moved /var dir to an additional drive of my vps. (I used this guide : https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-move-var-directory-to-another-partition).

The fstabs:

```
/dev/sda1 / ext4 errors=remount-ro,discard 0 1
/dev/sdb1 /mnt/mydisk ext4 nofail 0 0
/dev/sdb1 /var ext4 defaults 0 2
```

Now i want to move the /var dir to sda1.

i commented `#/dev/sdb1 /var ext4 defaults 0 2`

rebooted vps and launched rsync -aqxP /mnt/mydisk /var/*

my sda1 space growth, but i don't see the files..

what's wrong?

I think that i have a prolem in rsync command..

Comment: You do see the `/var` directory on `/sda1` ?

Comment: Yes, i see the dir /var on /sda1 after commenting #/dev/sdb1 /var ext4 defaults 0 2 and reboot.

Comment: what do you see when running ‘ls -la /var’? Note the * at the end of your rsync command may not do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical scenario that can be easily fixed by mounting your /var directory on a different partition. Let’s get started by attaching a new LVM, partitioning, and creating a desired file system.

Create a LVM Using New Disk: /dev/sdb

```
# pvcreate /dev/sdb
# vgcreate  vg_var /dev/sdb
# vgdisplay
# df -Th
# lvcreate -n lv_var -l +<PE Free Size>
# mkfs.xfs /dev/mapper/vg_var-lv_var
# lsblk
```

Create a new mount point and mount your new partition:

```
 # mkdir /mnt/var
 # mount /dev/mapper/vg_var-lv_var  /mnt/var/
```

Start Sync /var to the new temporary mounted partition

```
# rsync -aqxP /var/* /mnt/var
```

unmount the temporary Partition after a successful sync

```
# umount  /dev/mapper/vg_var-lv_var /mnt/var/
# lsblk
```

Edit your /etc/fstab to include a new partition and choose a relevant file system:

```
/dev/mapper/vg_var-lv_var  /var                 xfs     defaults        0 0
```

Reboot your system and you are done. Confirm that everything is working correctly and optionally remove the old var directory by booting to some Live Linux system etc.

Comment: Sounds ok. But remember that `rsync -aqxP /var/* /mnt/var` might **not** do what you want.

Comment: It worked for me...... You may experience problems while booting if the sync is not done correctly. At that point, you can comment on the /var item in the fstab file and start the sync to /var with the temp mount point again. once it's completed unmount the temp mount it will work.